# How do I reference instances from one node tree to a different one?

Tags: geometry-nodes

In node tree A, I have a grid, instancing buildings, themselves instancing spheres on top of them.

I have an object, to which I applied node tree B. This one creates curves that I want to proximity interact with the spheres from node tree A, and just the spheres.

As far as I know I can only reference objects in a node tree. But what I want is to reference the position of specific instances from a different node tree.

Does it has something to do with attributes perhaps? Can they cross over node trees?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please prepare some simple example using two node trees, showcasing your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by assigning a boolean value to the spheres with the node `Store Named Attribute` in the first node tree.

If you then use the geometry created with this node tree in another node tree, you can query this attribute there again with `Named Attribute`, and thus separate the geometry from the rest and use your curves with it.

I have built a simple example for you here that illustrates this situation:

[image]

In *NodeTreeA* I create the geometry and select the spheres:

[image]

In *NodeTreeB* I separate this selection from the rest and modify the curve created there:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Hello @quellenform and thank you for taking the time. I feel that I'm almost there  but can't plug the named attribute into the geometry proximity node. I cleaned up my file so you can have a look. [the file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l688xirkkqag61r/Question.blend?dl=0) Thanks in advance

Comment: @Enashka You are almost there! First you have to capture a boolean value with `Store Named Attribute` in the first node tree to mark the spheres. And then you have to integrate the geometry created with this node tree in the second node tree with `Object Info` and separate the marked geometry. Exactly as I described it. Here is your modified blend file:: https://blend-exchange.com/b/vlMOv64j/

Comment: That workd thanks. Except that the curves also now attach to the ground, when I needed them to just attach to the spheres. A workaround I found is to separate each steps of my node tree into different objects referencing each other and reference the one with just the balls to my pyramid.

Comment: @Enashka I'm sorry, that was my mistake now, I didn't look through the geometry carefully. You would have to separate the instances from the rest of the geometry first. I have a new file for you here: https://blend-exchange.com/b/LmSsKrNM/

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Enashka You are welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139727/discussion-between-enashka-and-quellenform).